# React uncontrolled input: better understanding of why it does not re-render on value change

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, controlled-component

**The code**

I have this simple `<form>` with both controlled and uncontrolled inputs.

([link to codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-wescoff-tjkl1?file=/src/App.js))

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const ControlledInput = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("controlled");

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Controlled: useEffect() cause value has changed to " + value);
  }, [value]);

  console.log("Controlled: re-render with " + value);

  return (
    <div>
      <label>Controlled input</label>
      <input
        name={"controlled"}
        value={value}
        onChange={(ev) => setValue(ev.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

const UncontrolledInput = () => {
  const [value, _setValue] = useState("uncontrolled");

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(
      "Uncontrolled: useEffect() cause value has changed to " + value
    );
  }, [value]);

  console.log("Uncontrolled: re-render with " + value);

  return (
    <div>
      <label>Uncontrolled input</label>
      <input name={"uncontrolled"} defaultValue={value} />
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <form>
      <ControlledInput />
      <UncontrolledInput />
    </form>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**What do I expect**

To see `console.log` messages after every change of input's values, both on controlled and uncontrolled inputs

**What do I get**

It happens just on controlled input, while not on the uncontrolled.

**The question**

I understand React handles uncontrolled inputs by its own. And, somehow, it avoids input to being re-rendered cause `value` is handled internally. But... why is this `useEffect` not running on further `value` changes? Just because there is not an explicit `setValue` call?

I'm interested in the real and good explanation of my previous incomplete assumption, but, most of all:

How can I make this `useEffect` to actually run any time `value` changes?

Comment: Following link has a very good explanation with code example https://daveceddia.com/useeffect-hook-examples/

Comment: "Just because there is not an explicit `setValue` call?" Exactly. React components rerender when state or props update, and since neither are in the uncontrolled component there are no effects to re-trigger upon subsequent renders.